# Create a relation matrix from a sequence (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, sequence

I have a sequence S :

```
  S= 'ABCD' % which means A<B<C<D
```

I want to convert S into a matrix M[i,j] which have to satisfy those conditions :

```
   M[i,j] , M[j,i] are random
   M[i,i] =0.5
   M[i,j] + M[j,i] = 1
   M[i,j] < M[j,i] % For example: if A<B then M[A,B] < M[B,A]
```

For example: if we have S = 'ABCD', the M matrix will be expected as follows:

```
      A      B    C    D
   A  o.5  0.25  0.2   0.1
   B  0.75 0.5   0.35  0.15
   C  0.8  0.65  0.5   0.4
   D  0.9  0.85  0.6   0.5
```

How to create that kind of above matrix from a given sequence ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This is a rather unconstrained problem.  There is more than one possible answer.

Comment: I don't see how `S` is used at all. Have you got any code that you've tried (even if it doesn't work correctly)?

Comment: S is the sequence of {A,B,C,D} ( which means A<B<C<D) . Base on the sequence, we will get different matrices. For example, the matrix which is generate from S = 'ABCD' will be different from 'BCAD' because of the above conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question it appears you want

- to fill the lower part of the matrix with random entries uniformly distributed on the interval (0,0.5) (so that condition 4 in your question be satisfied);
- the upper part is then computed according to condition 3; and
- the diagonal is determined by condition 2.

You can do that as follows:

```
n = 4; %// size
M = NaN(n); %// preallocate
M(1:n+1:end) = 0.5; %// fill diagonal
ind_lower = tril(true(n), -1); %// logical index for lower part
M(ind_lower) = 0.5*rand(n*(n-1)/2, 1); %// fill lower part
M_aux = NaN(n); %// auxiliary variable to fill upper part
M_aux(ind_lower) = 1-M(ind_lower).';
M_aux = M_aux.';
M(ind_lower.') = M_aux(ind_lower.'); %// fill upper part
```

Example result:

```
M =
    0.5000    0.5214    0.7573    0.5999
    0.4786    0.5000    0.9291    0.7891
    0.2427    0.0709    0.5000    0.5421
    0.4001    0.2109    0.4579    0.5000
```

Comment: I think you got the upper and lower triangular portions swapped, but why `M(1,4)+M(4,1) != 1`? Your code says it should. :D

Comment: Also `M(3,2), M(2,3)`. It looks like there's a problem with the anti-diagonal.

Comment: @beaker Thanks! Fixed now. The problem was the order in which the upper part was filled

Comment: @beaker After correcting my answer I saw yours, which uses a similar approach only simpler (+1 already)

Comment: one more question : When I have a cell array which includes many sequences : Cell= { ' ABCD ' , ' BDEG' , ' ABDF' } . How can I generate the matrixes M1 , M2 , M3 which have the same atribute as above ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. In fact, I didn't understand "_S= 'ABCD' % which means A<B<C<D_" in your question either. Anyway, if what you want is a significant change from your original question, it's better for you to post another question

Comment: Could you please tell me how to change the position of M[1,2] and M[2,1] please ? Because the rule is when A<B then M[A,B] < M[B,A]

Comment: In that case you need to transpose `M`: just do `M = M.';`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another similar approach:

```
n = 4;
M = tril(rand(n)*0.5, -1);
P = triu(1-M.', 1);
M = M + P + eye(n)*0.5;
```

Result:

```
M =

   0.500000   0.987433   0.711005   0.944642
   0.012567   0.500000   0.782633   0.902365
   0.288995   0.217367   0.500000   0.783708
   0.055358   0.097635   0.216292   0.500000
```

Comment: However, base on the above conditions, the matrix of S='ABCD' is different from the matrix which is generated from S='BADC'. How can I get the right matrix of the right sequence?

Comment: @kgk I still have no idea what you mean by these sequences. How do they relate to the resulting matrices? **How** is the matrix supposed to be different. Repeating "base [sic] on the above conditions" over and over doesn't help us in the least.

Comment: the sequences which I meantioned above are the strings 'ABCD'  or 'BADC'. Thanks for your comment !

Comment: @kgk This gives me no new information as to what these sequences *mean*.

Comment: @kgk Perhaps we could help if you told us what `A, B, C and D` correspond to (are they rows, columns, both, neither?) and then give *consistent* examples using the same data for strings `ABCD` and then some other string(s) telling us exactly what changed in each new matrix and why.

Comment: thanks for your advice ! I will explain clearer next time .